Configure what gets logged in event viewer
My server generates around 2.5GB of logs everyday and i just cant store it, upon some investigation i discovered that of my 854,608 logs 394,880 of them looks like this:
    The Windows Filtering Platform has permitted a connection.

Application Information:
    Process ID:     2160
    Application Name:   \device\harddiskvolume2\windows\system32\svchost.exe

Network Information:
    Direction:      Inbound
    Source Address:     192.168.15.25
    Source Port:        5353
    Destination Address:    224.0.0.251
    Destination Port:       5353
    Protocol:       17

Filter Information:
    Filter Run-Time ID: 81091
    Layer Name:     Receive/Accept
    Layer Run-Time ID:  44

and another 185,103 is the same thing but with System instead of \device\harddiskvolume2\windows\system32\svchost.exe.
What do i do with it ? And most important how do i make it stop ?

That means you have Windows Filtering Platform connections allow/drop auditing enabled.
WFP auditing is 100% useless and is disabled by default. It also has been known to have false positives - logging dropped connections when they aren't dropped.
Unless you know you need it, you should disable it in the Group Policy you have to configure auditing.
If not configured in policy, you can also disable it at the command prompt using auditpol.exe.
auditpol /set /subcategory:"Filtering Platform Connection" /success:disable  /failure:disable 

auditpol /set /subcategory:"Filtering Platform Packet Drop" /success:disable  /failure:disable 

https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/book/page.aspx?spid=chapter7#FiltDrop
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/auditing-and-logging
